# should I recompile all clang project when I want to add a new checker in Clang StaticAnalyzer?

Tags: llvm-clang, clang-static-analyzer

I follow the steps in the section **Checker Registration**
in the [manual page of clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/checker_dev_manual.html) one by one and can not find my checker from the output of the command

```
clang -cc1 -help | grep "analyzer"
```

So, I wonder if I should recompile the whole project? That is a burdensome job which I need almost several hours to compile it.

Comment: Are you certain you did all 3 steps correctly? Would you mind posting what you added to Checkers.td and the `void ento::register...` section from your checker code?

Comment: yeah, I just copy the code from the manual, you mean I don't need to compile the project that I can get the result?

Comment: Did you copy the code exactly? You'll need to change some things. You'll need to make sure you are using the name of your checker in all the necessary places.

Comment: I recompiled the clang project in release mode, it worked and I found my checker, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a build system like [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) or [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) when compiling llvm/clang. The build system automatically decides which parts need to be recompiled and which parts do not.

As an example, if you follow the steps to build clang [here](https://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html), step number 7 says to run the following commands:

```
mkdir build (in-tree build is not supported)
cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ../llvm
make
```

From that point forward every time you make changes you only need to re-run the `make` command from your build folder and make will automatically compile anything that needs to be recompiled.

If you want slightly faster recompile times you can install the ninja build system and use `cmake -G "Ninja" ../llvm` when first building the project and use the `ninja` command instead of `make` from that point forward.

Comment: I try to start to use visual studio to compile my project, however, I think what you said would help.